# iFrame/PHP Code is making Window within window, instead of changing pages?

Tags: php, iframe

I have a map embeded into the home page of my wordpress theme, I replaced the slidehow at the top with the map. I used an iframe for the map. So it fits perfectly, but when people click links inside the map, this is what happens:  (see screenshot)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9IF5.png

And below is the code for the file where the iframe map is embedded, I think the solution is just adding some simple line of code or something?

```
    <?php 
$slide_args = array( 
'post_type' => 'slide',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'ASC',
);
$slide_query = new WP_Query();
$slide_query->query( $slide_args );
$slide_post_count = $slide_query->post_count;
// print_r($slide_query);
?>
<!-- #mfn-offer-slider -->

<div class="container">

        <iframe src="http://www.Mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/leaflet-maps-marker-pro/leaflet-fullscreen.php?layer=1" width="100%" height="350px"></iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As php is server side script there is no way to achieve what you want.

You will have to modify the code of marker itself. Which is inside iframe

here is html code

```
<a href="test.html" target="_parent">ABC</a>
```

or with js

```
<a href="javascript:window.parent.location='test';" >ABC</a>
```

There is no way to do from same parent page as it may violate same-domain origin policy. and if you are working in same domain comment there is solution from parent page.

Comment: Oh so, you mean in the html of the link of the marker? Theres nothing to modify in the code I pasted above right?

Comment: yes. As php is server side script there is no way to achieve what you want.

Comment: It worked! so simple! Thanks Terry, you saved my night